# Model vs List<Model> when sending post request to controller using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have been trying to send a list model to controller using ajax but it seems it is not working at all

Model

```
public string MyModel {
   public string myfieldName {get;set;}
}
```

controller

```
 public JsonResult Create(List<myModel> list)
    {

        return Json("Success");


    }
```

post request

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

    var list= new Array();
    list = [{ myfieldName: 'ABC' }, { myfieldName: 'DEF' }];


    //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/Project/Create",
        data: JSON.stringify({ list }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
        }
    });
});
```

so when I send this through, I check the browser and I can see that the request payload is sent with json object list 
However when I go to controller the list is not binding it at all, so I check the http.context to check the request payload there and it all empty. 
on the other hand when I change the controller like below

sending request with only model

```
public JsonResult Create(myModel data)
{

    return Json("Success");


}
```

and change the js with below

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

var data ={};
data.myfieldName= "test";



//Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/Project/Create",
        data: data,
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
        }
    });
});
```

the only difference here is that I don't send as json, so my question what is the is  the difference between sending model vs a list of model using ajax 
and what can I change to get the controller to bind the data or accept a list of model data 
noting i'm using .Net core 2.0

Thank you

Comment: In your `AJAX` call, your `data` should be: `data: JSON.stringify(list),`

Comment: tried this as well, still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use this method to send my `Model` as a `List` to my `Controller` method. I will try to show you regarding your scenario, how you can do this:

AJAX:

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

    var list= new Array();
    list = [{ myfieldName: 'ABC'}, { myfieldName: 'DEF'}];


    //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
        $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Create","Project")",
            data:{"json": JSON.stringify(list)},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
            }
        });
    });
```

And you can receive your `Model` like this in your `Create` method:
Make sure to import the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
    List<string> myfieldName=new List<string>();
    //Access your array now
    foreach (var item in jsondata)
    {
      myfieldName.Add(item["myfieldName"]);
    }

    //Do something with the list here
    return Json("Success");
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: works like a charm, i receive the json string with data, now I have to figure out why my solution doesn't recognize using System.Web.Script.Serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to utilize unobtrusive AJAX. All you would need is to install Microsoft jQuery unobtrusive AJAX from your Nuget Package Manager.

Then, in your view, call the following:

```
@{using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", null, new AjaxOptions()
     {
          HttpMethod = "POST",
          // ...
     }
}))
{
     // Html code goes here
}
```

And also make sure that you include this at the bottom of your view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Then, you can have a normal ActionResult setup (instead of JsonResult) for your controller and accept an argument of List list.